Calling second custom tool w/in main tool ArcGIS Pro
I have two tools in an .tbx in ArcGIS Pro, ToolA and ToolB. I want to be able to call ToolB within ToolA. I need to keep them separate because I need to use ToolB independently in some cases but as part of a larger script in others. I have tried many methods but they won't work. Essentially they all get stuck saying that module 'arcpy' has no attribute 'mytools.ToolB'.
import arcpy

def CreateA(x, y):
    arcpy.AddMessage("Tool A Run")

    toolbox_path = r"S:\Procedural Standards\ArcGIS Pro\Tools\Tools in Development.tbx"
    tool_b_name = "ToolB"
    toolbox_alias = "mytools"

    if arcpy.Exists(toolbox_path):
       arcpy.AddMessage("Toolbox exists, importing toolbox")
       arcpy.ImportToolbox(toolbox_path, toolbox_alias)

       try:
           arcpy.AddMessage("Running Tool B...")
           getattr(arcpy, f"{toolbox_alias}.{tool_b_name}")(x, y)
           arcpy.AddMessage("Tool B completed successfully.")
       except Exception as e:
           arcpy.AddError(f"Failed to run Tool B: {e}")
   else:
       arcpy.AddError(f"Toolbox '{toolbox_path}' does not exist.")


x = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
y = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
CreateA(x, y)


Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour].  What exactly is the problem?  You've explained what you want to do, but haven't told us whether it's working, not working, or somewhere in between.  Please [edit] your question to include details of what happens when you run your script, including any error messages, and where exactly you're stuck.

I think its your getattr() line that is the problem, look at the code samples for the ImportToolbox function in help, it shows exactly how to call a custom tool.

If this is "case closed", please post an answer (not just a comment), and then accept that answer as correct.  Then other people will know this question is not still awaiting an answer.

Thank you, will do.

I ended up having to use an alias for the custom tool box in order to call the tool. So the syntax was first to create the alias arcpy.ImportToolbox(toolbox_path,alias). Then, I called the tool using the alias and the tool name arcpy.alias.tool_name(parameters).

No need to do the getattr this would just get a named attribute's value not the execute method of the tool.
getattr(arcpy, f"{toolbox_alias}.{tool_b_name}")(x, y)

replace above with either of the following
arcpy.<toolbox alias>.ToolB(x, y)
arcpy.<toolbox alias>_ToolB(x,y)

tool alias property (see default .pyt below)
class Toolbox:
    def __init__(self):
        self. Label = "Toolbox"
        self. Alias= "toolbox"

